# Create Matrix from redundant list

Tags: list, perl, matrix

I have an Input with a redundant list which looks like this:

```
Sample1.14  Water
Sample2.45  Air
Sample1.16  Dirt
Sample1.14  Water
Sample2.45  Air
Sample1.16  Dirt
Sample1.14  Water
Sample2.45  Air
Sample1.16  Dirt
Sample1.16  Dirt
Sample1.14  Dirt
Sample2.45  Air
Sample1.16  Air
```

I created a hash which counts how often each sample gives the result Water,Air,Dirt (note this is just example data but the structure is identical).

```
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    my $inPut = "ExampleSample";
    open(READ,$inPut) || die "Coult not read $inPut: $!";

    my %sampleHash;

    while (<READ>) {

        chomp;
        my @temp = split("\t",$_);

        my $sample = $temp[0];

        my $type = $temp[1];

        $sampleHash{$type}{$sample} += 1;

    }
```

This works as intended and gives as output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Dirt' => {
                      'Sample1.16' => 4,
                      'Sample1.14' => 1
                    },
          'Air' => {
                     'Sample1.16' => 1,
                     'Sample2.45' => 4
                   },
          'Water' => {
                       'Sample1.14' => 3
                     }
        };
```

Since this is quiet a bad data structure for further downstream stuff I would like to put this data into a matrix which I am somewhat lost at.

Desired Output or the transposed of this example, does not really matter:

```
    Sample1.14  Sample2.45  Sample1.16
Air     0           4           1
Dirt    4           0           4
Water   3           0           0
```

I am really stuck here, any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Your example has the wrong variable names.

Comment: In order to help, we would need to understand what your downstream stuff needs. If you don't know that, tell us what you intend to do with the data later. The structure you have now is very typical. Looking at the data I would have done the same. You group by type, and then count the samples. This corresponds to the table you showed insofar that the first key is the row, and the second key is the column.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Downstream I want to create an output file with the matrix structure in order to look which sample appears most often with which type but since the groupings are redundant I am not quite sure on how to get the data to a more R-readable format.

Comment: So your question boils down to how to turn this into a CSV file?

Comment: Apparently so...I was hoping to learn something on how to properly create matrices in perl but now I feel kind of stupid. But it seems...yes...

Comment: Well, there is no built-in data structure for a matrix. [A quick search](https://metacpan.org/search?q=matrix) reveals a few modules that might be helpful, but if all you want to do is transform the data so you can consume it easily with R, then a CSV file would be ideal, wouldn't it?

Comment: A CSV file would be ideal that is true. I already checked some modules for matrices but I wanted to avoid modules as much as possible in order to get better in Perl. But you are of course correct a CSV file would be ideal for R input.

Comment: Learning what's on cpan, which one to use for what problems and how to use them effectively is exactly how you will get better with Perl. Most other things are just programming. But learning the ecosystem is essential to being really effective. If course you also needs to know the language's kinks and edges, but that will come naturally. The cpan is open source. Module are just code. Read it. That's the best way to learn. :-) do you need help with the csv file?

Comment: Thanks for the help simbabque ! I think I got it worked out after you boiled my problem down so efficiently :P . Gave me another look on how to solve it. I have some minor kinks to work out but I think I got it. I may have to update the question if I get stuck again. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to create a unique list in Perl is to use the elements as hash keys with dummy values. After filling the hash you can get the unique list of values with `keys`.

```
my %samples;
$samples{"some value"} = 1;
$samples{"some other value"} = 1;
$samples{"some value"} = 1;
my @samples = sort keys %samples;
```

If you want to make Perl behaving like `awk`, you can use the split function with a single space argument.  And if you want to assign the result of a split to two variables you can use Perl's list notation.

```
my ($a, $b) = split ' ';
```

The complicated part is to build the table. This can be done with `for` loops or by `map`.  The use of `for` loops might be easier to read, but `map`s allow a more compact notation.

The following creates an array reference (square brackets) and fills the array with the return list of the `map` expression, prefixed by the `$t` value.  The `map` expression takes a pice of code and a list and executes the code for each element of the list.  The value of the current list element is available in the variable `$_`.

```
[ $t, map { $sampleHash{$t}{$_} or '0' } @samples ]
```

If you nest `map` expressions, you have to give the outer `$_` a name to  access it from the inner `map`, because the inner `$_` shadows the outer.

A basic way to format tables in Perl is to use Perl's report feature [perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html). For that you have to define a list of alternating lines: first a pattern line and then a value line.

If you put all together your example becomes this

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %sampleHash;
my %samples;
my %types;

while (<DATA>)
{
  chomp;
  my ($sample, $type) = split ' ';
  $sampleHash{$type}{$sample} += 1;
  $samples{$sample} = 1;
  $types{$type} = 1;
}

my @samples = sort keys %samples;
my @types = sort keys %types;

my @table =
    (['', @samples],
     map { my $t=$_; [ $t, map { $sampleHash{$t}{$_} or '0' } @samples ] } @types );

my $row;
format =
@<<<<<<  @||||||||||  @||||||||||  @||||||||||
@$row
.
for $row (@table) { write; }

__DATA__
Sample1.14  Water
Sample2.45  Air
Sample1.16  Dirt
Sample1.14  Water
Sample2.45  Air
Sample1.16  Dirt
Sample1.14  Water
Sample2.45  Air
Sample1.16  Dirt
Sample1.16  Dirt
Sample1.14  Dirt
Sample2.45  Air
Sample1.16  Air
```

which outputs this

```
         Sample1.14   Sample1.16   Sample2.45
Air           0            1            4
Dirt          1            4            0
Water         3            0            0
```

*Note:* Your desired output does not match your input.

In order to read a file you have to keep your code using `open`.  I have used the `__DATA__` section only to simplify the example in order to get a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You can "munge" your hash of hashes into an array of arrays and then input that into [Acme::Tools](http://search.cpan.org/~kjetil/Acme-Tools-0.21/Tools.pm)::pivot() or [Data::Pivot](http://search.cpan.org/~bdulfer/Data-Pivot-0.05/Pivot.pm)::pivot(). Like this:

```
use Acme::Tools;
my $data={
    'Dirt' => {
        'Sample1.16' => 4,
        'Sample1.14' => 1
    },
    'Air' => {
        'Sample1.16' => 1,
        'Sample2.45' => 4
    },
    'Water' => {
        'Sample1.14' => 3
    }
};
my @sample=uniq(sort map keys(%$_), values %$data);
my @element=sort keys %$data;
my $data2=[ map { my $x=$_; map [$x,$_,$$data{$x}{$_}||' 0'], @sample } @element ];
print tablestring([Acme::Tools::pivot($data2,"Element")]);
```

Output:

```
Element Sample1.14 Sample1.16 Sample2.45
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
Air              0          1          4
Dirt             1          4          0
Water            3          0          0
```